Imports could not be resolved 'flask_mail'
I was following a tutorial and I was to install flask_mail to use it for sending a reset password token for an email.
I ran the pip install flask-mail and it was successful but, I could not import it without vscode flagging it as a missing import.
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_mail import Mail

app = Flask(__name__)#For flask 
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '5791628bb0b13ce0c676dfde280ba245'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='sqlite:///site.db'
db=SQLAlchemy(app) #For SQL
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)#For Password Hash
login_manager=LoginManager(app)
login_manager.login_view='login'
login_manager.login_message_category='info'

from flaskr import routes

This was my init.py file for all imports all imports work fine except the mail import
